# Solve $\int \frac{\sin(\pi x) }{\ln x}dx$

Tags: integration

Wolfram Alpha thinks that it is unsolvable, but...

My solution so far:

$$\int \frac{\sin(\pi  x) }{\ln x}dx = \int \frac{e^{i\pi x} -e^{-i\pi x}}{2i\ln x}dx.$$

Let us split sum and focus on the first integral, using the Feynman's technique:

$$\int \frac{e^{i\pi x}}{\ln x}dx = I(0),  $$

$$ I(t)= \int \frac{e^{i\pi x}x^{-t}}{\ln x}dx, $$

$$ I'(t)= \int \frac{e^{i\pi x}x^{-t}(-\ln x)}{\ln x}dx = - \int e^{i\pi x}x^{-t}dx.$$

Substitute $-i\pi x = u$, $-i\pi dx = du$, $dx = \frac{du}{-i\pi}$,

$$ I'(t)=  \int e^{-u}\left(\frac{u}{-i\pi}\right)^{-t}\frac{du}{-i\pi}= \frac{1}{(-i\pi)^{-t+1}}\int e^{-u}u^{-t}du = \frac{1}{(-i\pi)^{1-t}} \Gamma (1-t).$$

Now I must integrate it with respect to $t$.

Any ideas how to solve it further or maybe you can suggest other method?

Comment: Feynman's trick is applicable to definite integrals, not to anti-derivatives.

Comment: In any case, you end up having to integrate an expression that doesn't look much simpler than the initial one...

Comment: These integrals tend to only be evaluated on improper definite bounds (still a difficult job in itself); finding an antiderivative of a non elementary function like this will give you a nasty series, or a whole host of special functions, or nothing - what is your motivation for a “closed” form?

Comment: @Tob Ernack important is not the simplicity, but what can i do with the expresion. any thought on this gamma, if it stays under the integral?

Comment: @FShrike finding the solution, no one found before is the motivation :D

Comment: The lack of definite bounds causes problems. You wrote $\cdots=\Gamma(1-t)$ but that equality would be true only if the bounds were $0,\infty$

Comment: @FShrike oh thanks i lot let the bounds be like that first :D. So can i now  substitute t=0 in the I'(t)?

Comment: Wolfram alpha probably knows all these tricks. If it cannot find an antiderivative, you cannot too.

Comment: @markvs For the OP’s benefit I’ll say that on the whole, this site can be better than wolfram at evaluating definite integrals, but I agree that an *in*definite integral cannot be found by a human if it cannot be found by a computer library.

Comment: I am not sure even about definite integrals. It is like playing chess with Stockfish.